# winpthreads license in a GPL project

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, gpl-3, bsd

I have a project that i have licensed under the GPL, and I would like to start working on parallelizing parts of it using OpenMP. To do this on windows using GCC, I apparently have to include the winpthreads license in my project, per the discussion [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/mingw-w64-public/thread/5238F91B.7010602@tdragon.net/), for example.

The license itself has an advertising clause similar to the 4-clause BSD license:

```
...
 *  * Neither the name of Lockless Inc. nor the names of its contributors may be
 *    used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without
 *    specific prior written permission.
...
```

I believe this is not compatible with the GPL. Is there any way to include this in my GPL project while still using the GPL, or am I out of luck if I want to use GCC/OpenMP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problematic clause in 4-clause BSD when it comes to GPL compatibility is the following:

> 3. All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software must display the following acknowledgement: 
>      This product includes software developed by the organization .

Not the one you provided. So as long as the license is similar to the 3-clause BSD license in all other aspects as well it is compatible with the GPL.

See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses for more about GPL compatible and incompatible licenses.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Seem that there is no problem after all. Excellent! I'll accept your answer when it lets me in 5 minutes.